# Anyone successfully used php_apc with symfony1.4?

Tags: php, symfony1, apc

I can only make symfony work properly by diabling `php_apc.dll`, very strange!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I am using it with Symfony 1.4 at the moment. I've got the latest XAMPP installed on a Windows 7 machine and I enabled APC on it.

I seem to remember that this was the source of some headache for me when I installed XAMPP for the first time a few months ago but all is working fine now.

Let me know if I can help out somehow, with settings info or something.

MORE INFO:

Thinking about this further, I think what's suggested in Cryo's link below is what I did when I started out (I had to replace the dll with another version)... but now that my Symfony project is created, APC is working clean out of XAMPP (I've switched machines in the middle of project and didn't need to replace the APC dll for the current one).

MY APC SETTINGS IN PHP.INI:

```
[PECL]
extension=php_apc.dll

[apc]
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 128M
apc.ttl = 7200
apc.user_ttl = 7200
apc.num_files_hint = 1024
apc.enable_cli = 1
```

(the APC part is the XAMPP default, I only uncommented the PECL line to enable APC)

Comment: Can you paste the apc setting here?What's your PHP's version?

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.1, APC Version 3.1.3p1, Symfony 1.4.1 ... let me dig out the APC settings for you, one sec.

Answer (score 0):

The following may provide some insight: http://forum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/82364/#msg_num_6

Comment: The php_apc version is 3.1.0,that should be the right version,otherwise I won't be able to install it at all

Comment: @user198729 From the link you provided on your other question about this issue there seems to be two different versions available for 5.3, have you tried the other build?  http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_apc-3.1-5.3-svn-20091026-vc9-x86.zip

Comment: I tried all I can try,3.1.0 is the only version I can install.

Comment: @user198729 If no available versions work for you in PHP 5.3 I would suggest downgrading to 5.2 if possible as the user in the post I referenced reported success.

Comment: I've temporarily disabled apc,hoping to hear some success reports with php5.3,symfony 1.4

Answer (score 0):

For me Zend optimizer needed disabling.

To do this edit `zend.ini`:

```
nano /etc/php.d/zend.ini
```

where `/etc/php.d/` is replaced by the path for your local installation:

remove or comment out line:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendOptimizer.so
```

and then restart apache :)

to find zend.ini path:

```
updatedb
```

followed by:

```
locate zend.ini
```